# How to style all ExtJs components with one color?

Tags: extjs, styles

in my app.css file, I have got a class for header and components color value.

I am using css not sass or scss.

```
.header-class {
   color: #1100aa !important;
}
```

and I want to change the color in theme setting in my frontend dialog.

How can I do this?

Comment: What Ext version are you using?

Comment: Without the use of SASS you have to grab the corret class. try: `x-title` or  `x-panel-header-title`

Comment: With SASS you can change the base-color, so that all components and all parts of the components are colored in your favorits color.

Answer (score 1):

Define a ui for the panel, see https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0-CE/modern/ext.Panel.html .css_mixin-panel-ui

```
@include panel-ui(
    $ui: 'dialog',
    $header-font-weight: normal,
    $header-padding: 5px 7px,
    $header-min-height: 46px,
    $header-min-height-big: 46px,
    $header-background-color: #3a3a3a,
    $header-padding-big: 0 10px 0 0,
)
```